# This linear operator has no eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, linear-transformations, eigenfunctions

Let $T : L^2(\mathbb R) \to L^2(\mathbb R)$ be a linear operator defined by 
$$(Tf)(x)=f(x+1).$$
Show that $T$ has no eigenvalues, i.e., there exists no $f \not= 0$ in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ such that $(Tf)(x)=\lambda f(x)$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb C$.

My work:

Okay, so the $\lambda=0$ case was straightforward for me: If $\lambda=0$, then $Tf(x)=0$, which means $f(x)=0$ because $T(0)=0$ since $T$ is linear.

But I am stuck on the case $\lambda \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$. How can I work with $f(x+1)=\lambda f(x)$ and show that $f(x)=0$?

Comment: $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $f \ne 0$  hence there exists $a$ such that $\int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} |f(x)|^2 dx \ne 0$

Comment: @Starfall this is not a counterexample: $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ functions are only defined up to a.e. equivalence, so this is the $0$ vector in that space and hence not an eigenvector.

Comment: @Starfall : $L^2$ is an Hilbert space of class of equivalence of functions, where for any $f,g \in L^2$, $f=g$ iff $\|f-g\|= 0$.

Comment: @par : once you know that for every $n < N$ : $f(x+n) = \lambda^n f(x)$ you get $\|f\|^2 \ge \sum_{n=0}^N \int_{n+a-\epsilon}^{n+a+\epsilon} |f(x)|^2 dx = \int_{a-\epsilon}^{a+\epsilon} |f(x)|^2 dx \sum_{n=0}^N |\lambda|^{2n}$

Comment: @user1952009: you are right; thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If $Tf = \lambda f$ for some unit vector $f\in L^2$, then $\|Tf\|=\|f\|$ implies $|\lambda|=1$. Therefore,
$$
             f(x+n)=\lambda^n f(x),\;\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
But that's a problem because it means that
$$
    \int_{k}^{k+1}|f(x)|^2dx = \int_{l}^{l+1}|f(x)|^2dx,\;\;\; k,l=1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
It's a problem because such $f$ could not be in $L^2$ unless $f=0$, thereby contradicting the assumption that $\|f\|=1$. So $T$ has no eigenvalues.

Comment: How exactly does $f(x+n)=\lambda^n f(x)$ imply $$\int_k^{k+1} |f(x)|^2 \, dx = \int_l^{l+1} |f(x)|^2 \, dx$$

Comment: Did you integrate both sides of $f(x+n)=\lambda^n f(x)$ and then performed a change of variable to the left-hand side?

Comment: If $ |\lambda| = 1$, then the function $ |f(x)| $ is periodic with period 1.

Comment: @Starfall But I'm assuming this argument shouldn't have to depend on the fact that $\lambda$ has to lie on the unit circle in the complex plane, because I'm hoping to see eventually that TrialAndError's argument would work for all of $\lambda \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: If $ |\lambda| \neq 1 $, then your function cannot be square integrable. (Unless it vanishes a.e., and the integral is zero.)

Comment: Trial why do you consider $\|Tf\| = \|f\|$ ??

Comment: @user1952009 $\|f\|=\sqrt{\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x)|^2\,dx}=\sqrt{\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f(x+1)|^2\,dx}=\|T(f)\|$.

Comment: @egreg  if $|\lambda| = 1$, which is my question ? ..

Comment: @user1952009 $\|f\|=\|T(f)\|=\|\lambda f\|=|\lambda|\,\|f\|$.

Comment: @egreg : WHY does he consider specially $|\lambda|=1$, my question is obvious. (and the answer too : he should not, see my comments above)

Comment: @user1952009 : You are correct: $\|Tf\|=\|f\|$ for all $f \in L^2$. Therefore if $f \ne 0$ and $Tf=\lambda f$, then $\|f\|=\|Tf\|=|\lambda|\|f\|$ implies $|\lambda|=1$ must be true.

Comment: @egreg : See my previous comment. $|\lambda|=1$ *must* hold if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, which I'm assuming in order to reach a contradiction.

Comment: Now I understood, sorry. $\qquad$  And I have another question : if we didn't know that we were in $L^2$, how could we make sense to the "eigenvectors" $f(x) = e^{i \lambda x}$ (needed for the spectral theorem) which are not in $L^2$, but can be defined say as $P_{[a,b]} f = e^{i \lambda x} 1_{[a,b]}$ where $P_{[a,b]}$ is a projection operator ? Is it how we start considering those kind of things : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection-valued_measure ?

Comment: @user1952009 : It's generally the case in such situations that "packets" of such eigenfunctions are in $L^2$, and are very nearly eigenfunctions, as close as you want if you form packets over small ranges of $\lambda$. For example $\int_{\lambda-\epsilon}^{\lambda+\epsilon}e^{i\mu x}d\mu$ IS in $L^2$ with an "approximate" eigenvalue of $\lambda$ for small $\epsilon$.

Comment: I never heard about those approximate spectrum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(functional_analysis)#Approximate_point_spectrum I'll try to see that, tks.